# The Sphere Does Not Admit a Metric Isometry into a Euclidean Space.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> **Problem.** There is no embedding $f:S^2\to \mathbf R^3$ such that for all points $p, q\in S^2$, we have $d_{S^2}(p, q)=d_{\mathbf R^3}(f(p), f(q))$.

Here $d_{S^2}$ is the metric on $S^2$ which is induced from the Riemannian metric induced on $S^2$ from $\mathbf R^3$, that is, $d_{S^2}(p, q)$ is the length of the shorter great circular arc joining $p$ and $q$. Here $d_{\mathbf R^3}(f(p), f(q))$ is the Euclidean distance between $f(p)$ and $f(q)$.

In [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/27641870.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A9ab54f324b9990a0b52a8d012de3463b) paper, it is remarked in the introduction that this problem can be solved by noticing that the curvature of $S^2$ does not vanish.

**I fail to see** how we are making use of curvature to solve this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider $X$, set of four points in $S^2(1)$ : $|pq|=|qr|=|pr| =
\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $|qt|=|tr|=\frac{\pi}{4},\ |pt|= \frac{\pi}{2}$.
So there is no isometric embedding $f$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{E}^3$.

[Add] In the above we have shown that there is no isometry from $T$ to
Euclidean space where $T$ is equilateral triangle of side length
$\frac{\pi}{2}$ in a sphere. Hence sphere is not flat.

In the paper, we can doubt that there may be local isometry. Hence
it takes a small equilateral triangle $T'$ in a sphere. A little
calculation (But idea is same to the above) show that there is no
isometry around $T'$. Hence the paper concludes that sphere is not
locally flat.

Comment: This is $(0,0,1)$ (North Pole), $(0,1,0)$ ("right" pole?), $(1,0,0)$ ("front" pole?), and $(\sqrt2/2,\sqrt2/2,0)$ (halfway between the last two), if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes. $X$ is a set of those points.

Comment: @HKLee This is a very simple solution. Thanks. But can you see how to use curvature in order to solve the problem?

Comment: @caffeinemachine : I add some.

Answer (score 9):

Take the equatorial circle $S^1\subseteq S^2$.  If $S^2$ is embedded in the strongly isometric sense you described, then $S^1$ is also.  But there is no strongly isometric embedding of a circle in Hilbert space since such an embedding would have to be a straight line (dealing with Gaussian curvature is a red herring).

Comment: You want $C^1$ embeddings?  Or $C^k$ embeddings for bigger $k$?  @CrashBandicoot

Comment: Well, out of the blue i'd say smooth (or at least more than $C^2$). But I am open to know if the $C^1$ case is different.

Comment: @CrashBandicoot, this sounds like an interesting question.  One would need to be more knowledgeable about Nash's proof than I am to answer it :-)  Gromov at some point wrote down a version of Nash's proof but he doesn't answer mail so easily.  Notice that there is a vast difference between the $C^1$ case and the $C^k, k\ge2$ case (the proofs are completely different).  I suggest posting  this as a question here at MSE or MO.